# Instancia de screen en kivymd en .kv

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Hola amigos resulta que tengo dos clase que es una instancia de screen en mi .py results que llamo esas clases desde .kv y la primera screen funciona de perfección pero cuando llama la segunda clase en .kv y le agrego un mdtoolbar me muestra un espacio en la parte superior cómo se ve en la imagen a continuación : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por qué pasa esto tengo mi código .kv así:

```
<SecondScreen>:
    name: "Valcamera"
    imgvision: capture
    camButton: validateCamera

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:
            title: app.title
            #elevation: 10
            left_action_items: [["camera-gopro", lambda x: x]]
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color     

        #Cramos la caja principal
        BoxLayout:
            #id: box
            padding: dp(20)
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
            spacing: dp(20)
            orientation: "vertical"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}

            #Creamos los botones que integrara el scroll
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: None, None
                width: self.minimum_width
                height: dp(56)
                spacing: "5dp"
                #pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

                Label:
                    markup: "True"
                    text: "[b]Validacion de Camara[/b]"
                    color: app.theme_cls.text_color
                    font_size: "40sp"
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: self.texture_size
                    #spacing: "10dp"

            #Ponemos las pantalla con la camara
            BoxLayout:                  
                #camera_display: capture
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(290)
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Image:
                    id: capture
                    #source: 'logo.png'
                    opacity: 1 if self.texture else 0
                    size_hint_x: 1.0

            BoxLayout:                    
                #camera_button: validateCamera
                size_hint: None, None
                width: self.minimum_width
                height: dp(56)
                spacing: "10dp"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

                MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                    id: validateCamera
                    markup: "True"
                    font_size: dp(20)
                    text: "[b]Validar[/b]"
                    icon: "eye-check-outline"
                    size_hint_y: .8
                    on_release:
                        root.init_camera()

                MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                    markup: "True"
                    font_size: dp(20)
                    text: "[b]Volver[/b]"
                    icon: "arrow-left-circle"
                    size_hint_y: .8
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "Menu"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                        root.after()
```

tambien agrego el archivo donde tengo el .py que declaro el screen para utilizarlo desde el kv

```
class SecondScreen(Screen):
    imgvision = ObjectProperty()
    camButton = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._cap = None

    def init_camera(self):
        self.camButton.disabled = True
        if not self.imgvision.texture:
            self.camButton.text = "Iniciando Cámara"

            if self._cap is None:
                self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

            if self._cap is None or not self._cap.isOpened():
                self.camButton.text = "Cámara no disponible"
                Clock.schedule_once(self._btn_restart, 2)
            else:
                self.camButton.text = "Detener"
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 30.0)
                self.camButton.disabled = False

        else:
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            self.imgvision.texture = None
            self._cap.release()
            self._cap = cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            self._btn_restart()

    def _btn_restart(self, *args):
        self.camButton.text = "Iniciar"
        self.camButton.disabled = False

    # Actualiza el frame que se muestra como imagen
    def update(self, dt):
        ret, img = self._cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
        validatorcam = Texture.create(size=(img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        validatorcam.blit_buffer(img.tostring(), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.imgvision.texture = validatorcam
```

Espero me hacen una manito pareciera que quiere heredar el mdtoolbar del primer screen, espero me ayude. Amigos gracias.

Comment: Hola Carlos, nunca debes agregar código como una imagen, las imágenes pueden ser muy aclaratorias, como la primera pero siempre accesorias y nunca para código o errores. El problema es que dificultan la legibilidad, principalmente en dispositivos móviles, no permiten la fácil reproducción del código al no poder copiar y pegar directamente y además no indizan para futuras vistas. Todo ello dificulta mucho que recibas respuestas rápidas y correctas y es posible que la pregunta termine con votos negativos e incluso cerrada.

Comment: Edita  y agrega la parte relevante del código como texto, todo el contendido de `<SecondScreen>` del kv y su clase en .py (ésta última solo si modifica la composición gráfica, si solo tiene lógica es irrelevante).

Comment: ok amigo vale voy a arreglarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos creo que encontre la solucion espero que me digan si es la forma correcta o tengo que modificar algo por ahora esta funcionando gracias por sus ayudas asi puse el codigo .kv:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation:"vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        title: app.title
        elevation: 10
        left_action_items: [["camera-gopro", lambda x: x]]
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    # Le paso los screen al boxlayout principal
    ScreenManager:
        MenuScreen:
        SecondScreen:

# Declaramos el menu de la la aplicacion
<MenuScreen>:
    name: "Menu"

    #Creamos un box para crear nuestro scroll
    BoxLayout:
        #id: box
        padding: dp(20)
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size
        spacing: dp(20)
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}


        #Creamos los botones que integrara el scroll
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: None, None
            width: self.minimum_width
            height: dp(56)
            spacing: "30dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

            Label:
                markup: "True"
                text: "[b]Menu[/b]"
                color: app.theme_cls.text_color
                font_size: "50sp"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                #spacing: "10dp"

#Screen de validacion de camara web solo funcionamiento
<SecondScreen>:
    name: "Valcamera"
    imgvision: capture
    camButton: validateCamera

    #Cramos la caja principal
    BoxLayout:
        #id: box
        padding: dp(20)
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size
        spacing: dp(20)
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}

        #Creamos los botones que integrara el scroll
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: None, None
            width: self.minimum_width
            height: dp(56)
            spacing: "5dp"
            #pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

            Label:
                markup: "True"
                text: "[b]Validacion de Camara[/b]"
                color: app.theme_cls.text_color
                font_size: "40sp"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                #spacing: "10dp"

        #Ponemos las pantalla con la camara
        BoxLayout:                  
            #camera_display: capture
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(290)
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Image:
                id: capture
                #source: 'logo.png'
                opacity: 1 if self.texture else 0
                size_hint_x: 1.0   
# Tercera screen para registrto de usuarios
```

Gracias amigos